# command shell and 128 bytes

Tags: windows, memory-management, command-line, popen

This [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) particular example, why only 128 bytes are being allocated to psBuffer?
I tried modifying the command to "dir /s c:\" which gives a lot more than 128 bytes output but program runs just fine without any overflow.

I am curious to know about the significance of 128 bytes in this example.

Comment: Seems like only 128 bytes are being read per line...so the large number of files returned by dir /s doesn't really matter, what matters is the output of each line returned by dir command. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the size of a buffer, and the code reads up to 128 bytes at a time into this buffer *in a loop*.

Comment: yea, I just figured that out. But why only 128 bytes?

Comment: It doesn't really matter too much, but having it longer than a typical line makes sense. If you change all the 128s in the code to 64 or 256 or 4096 it should still work. (Note that this is a very bad code example from you-know-who - the 128s should all be defined as a single `const`).

Comment: it doesn't matter. you could allocate more if you wanted to; i think 128 is an arbitrary choice here.

Comment: Because 128 bytes is long enough for most input - the program will truncate anything longer.  The person who wrote the sample thought that 128 was adequate - it is just a sample after all.  If you want to know why 128 and not 96 or 200, it's probably because programmers like to think in powers of two, and the author probably thought that 64 was too small.

Comment: the program won't truncate - as @Paul pointed out, it's in a loop here.